# C# - Make a special loop?

Tags: c#, variables, loops

How can I make a loop that will start all over again whenever I want to, let's say i want to make a loop start over whenever my variable

```
VarOfLoop++ ;
```

get summed by 1, the loop will start over again;
And how can I end this loop? Like for a for each we use "break;"

Comment: `break` works in for loops too.

Answer (score 8):

If you use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop then you can control the value of the iterator.  Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someUpperLimit, i++)
{
    // do something, iterating over some values with "i" as the index
    if (someCondition)
        i = -1; // re-start the loop (i will increment to 0 on the next iteration)
    else if (someOtherCondition)
        break; // exit the loop
}
```

Comment: Lol was thinking sth like a complicated while loop, but lol a for loop will do, i feel so stupid :D

Comment: Doesn't quite restart the loop as after a restart, i will be 1 (not zero as expected).

Comment: @grantnz: Good point, and should be discovered by some quick debugging after which it can just be changed to -1.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking about continuous loop then you may try with while loop as:

```
while(true)
{
 //your codes to execute
}
```